# Controlling Categories in Script Validation Tools - Expanding Groups By Default

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-script-tool, tool-validation

The validation tab in your script tool properties allows you to put parameters in categories. The [help states](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00150000000v000000#GUID-4BFCB0B1-80CA-48BB-AF78-655FF528A9BA):

> Put parameters in different categories. Categories are expandable
>   window shades with a collection of parameters.

[image]

I am using the categories to organize my parameters, so I don't care about the expandable/collapsible feature;  it just adds a lot of time to the user.  This is all within a normal toolbox, not a script toolbox.  v10.1

Does anyone know how to have these categories expanded by default?

Here is my only validation code.  I am only utilizing categories.  The other parts are the default.

```
def initializeParameters(self):
    """Refine the properties of a tool's parameters.  This method is
    called when the tool is opened."""
    self.params[0].category = "General"
    self.params[1].category = "General"
    self.params[2].category = "Inudaciones"
    self.params[3].category = "Cienegas"
    self.params[4].category = "DrenajesPrincipal"
    self.params[5].category = "DrenajesSensillos"
    self.params[6].category = "Inudaciones"
    self.params[7].category = "Cienegas"
    self.params[8].category = "DrenajesPrincipal"
    self.params[9].category = "DrenajesSensillos"
    return
```

Comment: Can you include a link to the Help that you mention, and also state the version of ArcGIS that you are using, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible in python, but you can by using a custom stylesheet.

1. Copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Stylesheets\MdDlgContent.xsl" to the same folder as your script.
2. Edit  line 467 to remove `STYLE="display:'none';"`, i.e. change:

   ```xsl
   <DIV ID="{PropertyGroupName}" STYLE="display:'none';" onclick="window.event.cancelBubble = true;">
   ```

   to

   ```xsl
   <DIV ID="{PropertyGroupName}" onclick="window.event.cancelBubble = true;">
   ```
3. Then in your script tool properties, set the stylesheet property to your edited.xsl.

   [image]

Comment: how on this green earth would you find out this? I am flabbergasted. This is not so well documented!

Comment: @Alex Modifying the stylesheet to customize a tool has been known about for a while. There's some old documentation here http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/documenting_tools_and_toolboxes/changing_tool_dialog_appearance.htm and a few questions here qnd on the Esri Geonet forum. Not sure if there's more up to date documentation. Once you know where to look, it's just a matter of figuring out what html/css needs changing.

Comment: Sure, but it would take many trial & error attempts before being able to accomplish the task. Wish we had more updated docs on that... Thanks for posting the answer, absolutely brilliant.

Comment: I had given up on style sheets, because of the little documentation and lack of knowledge base, even from esri personnel.This is good.  Any idea how to change the order so its not sorted alphabetical?

Comment: @Rex no, not using the xsl transform method.  The categories are passed in reordered to begin with.  I suggest the simple method of numbering your categories - `self.params[0].category = "1. General"` and  `self.params[2].category = "2. Inudaciones"` etc...

Comment: @Luke do you know if there's a way to move the categories up so they're not at the bottom of the script? Perhaps between two "non category" parameters?

Comment: @ATCH_torn possibly but not easily. The category and non-category parameters are both styled in loops so you'd need to really customise the xsl rather than just changing one bit.