# Adding box to toolbox created with ArcPy (only visuals)?

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, python-toolbox

I was wondering if there is a way I could easily include three parameters into a box (red box in the example) and so when there are a lot of inputs it's easier for a user to spot what data belongs to what sets of inputs.

Is there a way to give a title to the box ("Summary text" in red in the example) as well? In the example below, for example, I want to include `param0`, `param1` and `param2` into a box.

I'm hoping there is something built into `arcpy` rather than using third-party libraries.

```
import arcpy, os

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""
        self.tools = [Tool]
class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = ""
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            datatype = "Folder", direction = "Input",
            parameterType = "Required", name = "Summary_1",
            displayName = "Field 1")

        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            datatype = "String", direction = "Input",
            parameterType = "Required", name = "Summary_2",
            displayName = "Field 2")
        param1.type = "ValueList"
        param1.filter.list = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]

        param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
            datatype = "File", direction = "Output",
            parameterType = "Required", name = "Summary_3",
            displayName = "Field 3")

        param3 = arcpy.Parameter(
            datatype = "Boolean", direction = "Input",
            parameterType = "Optional", name = "Date_1",
            displayName = "Replace Date?")

        param4 = arcpy.Parameter(
            datatype = "String", direction = "Input",
            parameterType = "Optional", name = "Date_2",
            displayName = "Enter Date to replace")        

        params = [param0, param1, param2, param3, param4]
        return params


    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        return
```

[image: Box with a title ("Summary text")]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @Alex's answer, specify the [`category`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_4BB1F5030E8645F0985630DC835D94B5) for your input parameters:

```
param.category = "Category text"
```

Then follow the steps I outlined in my previous answer: [Controlling Categories in Script Validation Tools - Expanding Groups By Default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUagF.png) to display the category expanded by default.

Then on line 439 of your custom .xsl file use some inline CSS styling to add a border.

Change:

```
STYLE="cursor:hand;" border="1" bordercolor="buttonface"
```

To

```
STYLE="cursor:hand;border-collapse: collapse;border: 1px solid black;"
```

You can play around with border thickness (i.e 2px) and border colour (or any other CSS styling you like).

Then again as per @Alex's answer, add the `stylesheet` property to point to the modified `.xsl` file:

```
class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = ""
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False
        self.stylesheet = r"Path\to\MyCustom.xsl"
```

Voila:

[image]

Comment: very very cool!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for [`category`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/creating-tools/defining-parameters-in-a-python-toolbox.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_4BB1F5030E8645F0985630DC835D94B5) for your input parameters.

Just add

`param.category = "Summary text"`

for each input parameter and then your tool UI would look like this:

[image]

However, mind that by default:

> Categories are always shown after noncategorized parameters

However, it's possible to alter this by following the steps outlined in this answer: [Controlling Categories in Script Validation Tools - Expanding Groups By Default](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226569/controlling-categories-in-script-validation-tools-expanding-groups-by-default). The instructions would differ in the last step as you are working with the Python toolbox, not the script tool.

In the source code, add the `stylesheet` property to point to the modified `.xsl` file:

```
class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = ""
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False
        self.stylesheet = r"C:\GIS\MdDlgContent.xsl"
```

Then refresh the toolbox in ArcMap and open the tool. The category should be expanded by default (tested myself on 10.5).

Comment: Thanks Alex, I was hoping for a box, but this may be another way of looking at this. By default the categories are collapsed which can be confusing for the user where to input. Is there a way i can control the collapse feature of category so it's not collapsed by default?

Comment: Sorry, @Curtis, the standard Python toolbox functionality will only take you this far. If you have time to learn a new framework, take a look at PyQT, me and other people were able to create tools with custom UI that could be run from ArcGIS Desktop interface

Comment: this may seem possible according to this thread: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226569/controlling-categories-in-script-validation-tools-expanding-groups-by-default

Comment: But my stylesheet is greyed out, and can't change the default stylesheet in the toolbox

Comment: @Curtis, good catch. I thought this is only possible with the script toolbox, but apparently it works even with Python toolboxes. I've updated my answer and tested, it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Alex, i have accepted Luke's answer as originally wanted a box, but good to know standard capabilities of python toolbox can be overcome with stylesheet!

Comment: np, Luke is legendary :)