# Collapsing arcpy script parameter categories by default?

Tags: arcpy, tool-validation

Within an `arcpy` script, I've set up categories using the style sheet found in the ArcGIS installation folder. I have a couple categories created within the tool validator.

```
....
def initializeParameters(self):
    self.params[2].category = "Intersections"
    self.params[3].category = "Intersections"
    self.params[4].category = "Intersections"
    self.params[5].category = "Intersections"
    return
```

This shows my parameters in their proper categories, however, when you start the script, the categories are shown expanded by default. Is there something in the style sheet I can change to make sure they are collapsed by default?

[image: script]

I'm also curious if anyone knows of a way to move these categories up and above some other "non category" parameters in the script.

Comment: Found my own answer posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226569/controlling-categories-in-script-validation-tools-expanding-groups-by-default).